The North American Bitcoin Conference, Chicago, 2014 - Sponsorship Proposal
I would like to attend The North American Bitcoin Conference, Chicago, 2014 and promote Stack Exchange and specifically Bitcoin.StackExchange.com and the community there.

Who - The North American Bitcoin Conference is one of the most attended Bitcoin events in the world and the upcoming Chicago conference will be the most attended Bitcoin event in America to date. Approximately 1500 attendees will gather to hear leaders and titan in the industry. Persons involved with Blockchain.info, Ripple Labs, Bitpay, Litecoin, Ethereum, and more are slotted to give lectures or sit on discussion panels.
What - The conference is The North American Bitcoin Conference.
When - The conference takes place on July 19th and 20th, 2014.
Where - The conference will be held at the McCormick Place South Building in Chicago, Illinois, USA.
Why - I will commit to serve the community and Bitcoin.SE in the following ways:


The first immediate thing I can commit to is questions. I will surely have many, and quite a few will be right at home as a post here on Bitcoin.SE.
I can also commit to an added ability to make top notch answers. Great site content is always in demand.
I can also commit to getting answers from specific persons or lectures. If approved for sponsorship, I will make another meta post with the conference schedule and will attend sessions based on user input and attempt to get answers for any burning questions.
I will also write a summary and review of every lecture/panel I attend and post it to meta.
The community here would benefit from added expert users. This conference is going to be packed full of experts and I will do everything I can to make them users. I will pitch Bitcoin.StackExchange as the go to place for expert questions and answers to everyone I meet. In time, I too will become one of these experts and this conference is a great place to gain valuable knowledge that is unavailable elsewhere. In turn, that knowledge will be posted to Stack Exchange first. In my opinion, this is the most valuable thing the community can gain by supporting my sponsorship.



This post is formatted according to the suggestions to formally request for Stack Exchange sponsorship.

Get in touch with us with a link to this, and we can go from there. We do sometimes help really engaged members of communities attend events, and we'll give you a bunch of SE swag to give away while you're there.
The site could definitely use some users that are past the 'less than beginner' experience level asking questions, so if you think there'd be an opportunity to get some here, I'd be willing to push for getting you there to do it.
There may or may not be some tax matters to talk about, as well as other monetary details that are probably left best to email ;)

I have just submitted the information requested in the MSE post through the contact form. I eagerly await your response.

I have contacted SE, but have not received a reply. I know it is still early, but I just want to make sure they have received it.

@fredsbend That form is processed every week, so you should hear from us by Friday :)
